# Splitting XML into multiple xml files

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that has the data for multiple pictures such as GPS coordinates, date/time, and some image data that I need to split into several XML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
    <Placemark>
        <name> //picture 1 info <name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates> //gps 1 cords <coordinates>
        <Point>
    <Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name> //picture 2 info <name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates> //gps 2 cords <coordinates>
        <Point>
    <Placemark>
<Document>
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
File 1:
<Placemark>
<Name> //picture 1 info <name>
<Point>
    <coordinates> //gps 1 cords <coordinates>
<Point>
<Placemark>

File 2:
<Placemark>
<Name> //picture 2 info <name>
<Point>
    <coordinates> //gps 2 cords <coordinates>
<Point>
<Placemark>
```

.....I read this question:
 [Split XML in Multiple XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056910/split-xml-in-multiple-xml-files)

and tried to modify the code a little bit for my file after importing everything. Wondering if anyone had any good ideas on how to modify my code to do the spit like in the question above.

Comment: Make sure you close your tags properly, ie `<Point></Point>`

Comment: You have this tagged as Android... is that what language/system you're coding it on?  Or are you just doing it in Java?  Or C#?

Comment: @Tyler Ferraro I am writing it in Java, but I am going to be implementing it into an Android app down the road

Comment: Learn the basics of XML.  You are not using closing tags.  There's millions of XML tutorials online, so there's no excuse to be presenting such broken XML in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic structure you could use if programming on the Android.  This would open an xml file from a web address (R.string.XmlUrlAddress).  It would then parse the string and write to another file, probably stored on your Android device?

The commented areas are code that I didn't write rather than comments on what the code is doing.  I didn't want to take the time to look up the file io code which should be pretty straight forward.

```
URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.XmlUrlAddress));
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Placemark");
String[] files = new String[nodeList.getLength()];

for (int i=0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    files[i] = "file" + i + ".xml";
    //Create and open files[i] file.
    //Write opening tag.  "<Placemark>"

    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    Element element = (Element)node;

    NodeList nameList = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
    Element name = (Element)nameList.item(0);
    nameList = name.getChildNodes();
    String name = nameList.item(0).getNodeValue();
    //Write name to file.  "<name>" + name + "</name>"

    NodeList pointList = element.getElementsByTagName("Point");
    String[] points = new String[pointList.getLength()];

    //Write opening Points tag. "<Points>"
    for (int j=0; j < pointList.getLength(); j++) {
        Node cNode = pointList.item(j);
        Element cElement = (Element)cNode;

        NodeList coordinateList = element.getElementsByTagName("coordinates");
        Element coordinateElement = (Element)coordinateList.item(0);
        coordinateList = coordinateElement.getChildNodes();
        points[j] = coordinateList.item(0).getNodeValue();

        //Write points[j] to file. "<coordinates>" + points[j] + "</coordinates>"
    }
    //Write end Points tag.  "</Points>"
    //Write end document tag.  "</Placemark>"
    //Close file
}
```

Comment: Congrats on answering a question that is 5 years old and being humble about it.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Placemark">
    <xsl:result-document href="Placemark{position()}.xml">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there is a better way, but you could look into a SAX XML Parser, and then parse to the place that you want to cut the file at, and cut the file (make sure you end with the proper tags, and then start the tags again for the next file otherwise you will have 2 invalid xml files).

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question, but maybe this will help to somebody. In SO are a lot of answers etc, so I tried to made something universal. [Here](https://github.com/hrabosch/split-xml/releases) is my simple SWING app which saved me. I had a huge file where was PRODUCT as root element and Products as item elements. So if somebody need to load structure, select root element (which will be in all files) and item element which would be surround by root element, this can help you.