# Splitting an xml without creating new element in java to another file

Tags: java, xml, file

Below is my XML and I want to split that into another file without
creating a new element.
Is there a way to split that XML based on the child node to another XML
without creating new tag?

```
File 1.xml
<Envelope>
<Data>
<SomeData>SampleData</SomeData>
<NextData>NextData</NextData>
</Data>
<Body>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Age>12</Age>
<Country>India</Country>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

File1 is an existing one and I want file2 to have only contents of body
as shown below

```
File2.xml
<Body>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Age>12</Age>
<Country>India</Country>
</Body>
```

Also I want the file2 to be a new file but I don't want
to have any new elements created.
The examples i referred here had a way to do this only
by creating a new element
Below link uses creating new element

```
*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056910/split-xml-in-multiple-xml-files*
```

code I referred:

```
public class XmlSplit {

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
File input = new File("input.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//T0020/IRP_ACCOUNT", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

int itemsPerFile = 5;
int fileNumber = 0;
Document currentDoc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Node rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("T0020");
File currentFile = new File(fileNumber+".xml");
for (int i=1; i <= nodes.getLength(); i++) {
Node imported = currentDoc.importNode(nodes.item(i-1), true);
rootNode.appendChild(imported);

if (i % itemsPerFile == 0) {
writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);

rootNode = currentDoc.createElement("T0020");
currentFile = new File((++fileNumber)+".xml");
}
}

writeToFile(rootNode, currentFile);
}

private static void writeToFile(Node node, File file) throws Exception {
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(new FileWriter(file)));
}
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the XSLT transformation and transform it.
Java Codes:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("Split.xslt"));
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

Source text = new StreamSource(new File("File1.xml"));
transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("File2.xml")));
```

File: Split.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/Envelope/Body"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Body>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Age>12</Age>
    <Country>India</Country>
</Body>
```

Comment: Thanks....works like charm!!!but is there a way to skip the tag "body"and have remaining fields in file2?

Comment: Sure, in the Split.xsl change this `<xsl:copy-of select="/Envelope/Body/node()"/>`

Comment: i have another question in the below link... can you suggest an answer  as well either in java or xslt?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149000/splitting-an-xml-based-on-the-contents-of-xml-either-using-java-or-xslt