# Java: How to split XML stream into small XML documents with parents node. VTD-XML

Tags: java, xml, sax, vtd-xml

I need to read a large xml with VTD XML and XPath and split results in multiple nodes.
I found some solutions [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071797/soa/cut--paste--split--and-assemble-xml-documents-with-vtd-xml.html) but it split nodes but without parents information.

What why I'm looking for:

XPath string: **/CATALOG/MAIN/CD**
Based on XPath document should be splitted

1) Initial document:

`<CATALOG>
    <MAIN id="1">
        <CD>
            <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
            <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        </CD>
        <CD>
            <TITLE>Empire Dummy</TITLE>
            <ARTIST>John Doe</ARTIST>
        </CD>
        <USEFUL>Useful node</USEFUL>
    </MAIN>
    <MAIN id="2">
        <CD>
            <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
            <ARTIST>Gary More</ARTIST>
        </CD>
    </MAIN>
    <IGNORED>Ignored node</IGNORED>
</CATALOG>`

2) Results:
 Document 1:

`<CATALOG>
    <MAIN id="1">
        <CD>
            <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
            <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        </CD>
        <USEFUL>Useful node</USEFUL>
    </MAIN>
</CATALOG>`

Document 2:

`<CATALOG>
    <MAIN id="1">
        <CD>
            <TITLE>Empire Dummy</TITLE>
            <ARTIST>John Doe</ARTIST>
        </CD>
        <USEFUL>Useful node</USEFUL>
    </MAIN>
</CATALOG>`

Document 3:

`<CATALOG>
    <MAIN id="2">
        <CD>
            <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
            <ARTIST>Gary More</ARTIST>
        </CD>
    </MAIN>
</CATALOG>`

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Best regards!

Comment: have a look on this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056910/split-xml-in-multiple-xml-files)

Comment: You mean appending root element in front? You should be able to do it programmaticly.. can you?

Comment: Yes I mean append root element but without sibling node. I need some useful links how to do this with vtd-xml

Comment: I can come up with another piece of code that does what you described, but then you may come back with some what moer complicated use cases... :(

Comment: I'm not sure if exist more complicated use case for splitting. If be honest I'm not sure if is possible to do that with some SAX-based parser. I implemented that with standard DOM manipulation and Node recursion but it's terrible slow :( .

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that does what you described in vtd-xml. let me know if there is any question.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class splitTest {

    public static void  main(String[] a) throws VTDException,java.io.IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (vg.parseFile("C:\\Users\\Jimmy Zhang\\workspace\\ximple-dev\\DOMTest\\test111.xml", false)){
            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
            ap.selectXPath("/CATALOG/MAIN");
            byte[] header = "<CATALOG>".getBytes();
            byte[] tail = "</CATALOG>".getBytes();
            int i = -1,j=0;
            while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
                long l = vn.getElementFragment();
                FileOutputStream fops = new FileOutputStream("c:\\xml\\output"+j+".xml");
                fops.write(header);
                fops.write(vn.getXML().getBytes(), (int)l, ((int)(l>>32)));
                fops.write(tail);
                fops.close();
                j++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach but i need more complicated split logic, and I'm not sure if SAX or VTD-XML can perform it. Your approach will fail if I add one more CD node each other. I edited my question with complete example.

Comment: I think that the split logic is the most important thing here, vtd-xml is only a tool and the app you are creating is driven primary by the split logic here, not by tools itself.... it might end up being a sizable piece of code ...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author what should be the approach if my split should be based on size or number of nodes per file. Ex : 1st split file should contain 500 nodes so on second.

Answer (score 0):

Herez my approach...

Use some xml parsing libraries e.g javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
Create a DOM for your input xml file...
For each node encountered, create a new output file Document.xml e.g Document1.xml (add the child node under  parent.

You might refer http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory for sample java code to parse xml using java.xml.parsers.* package (look for loadQuestions example)

Comment: I implemented already with standart XPath reader and DocumentBuilderFactory but is too slow. I need some faster approach based on Sax and VTD-XML.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. Here is my approach based on standard SAX parsing.

1) Created custom SaxHandler:

`
public class CustomSAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {

```
private Stack<XmlNodeInfo> nodeStack = new Stack<XmlNodeInfo>();
private List<String> xPaths;
private XmlNodeInfo rootNode;
private final NamespaceContext namespaceContext;
private List<XmlNodeInfo> resultNodes;

public CustomSAXHandler(String xpath, XmlNodeInfo rootNode, NamespaceContext namespaceContext) {
    this.rootNode = rootNode;
    this.namespaceContext = namespaceContext;
    resultNodes = new ArrayList<XmlNodeInfo>();
    xPaths = splitXpaths(xpath);
}

@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    String element = "<" + qName + getAttributes(atts) + ">";
    if (!nodeStack.empty()) {
        rootNode = nodeStack.peek();
    }

    if (matchDefinedXpath(qName)) {
        XmlNodeInfo newNode = new XmlNodeInfo(qName);
        rootNode.addChild(newNode);
        nodeStack.push(newNode);

        newNode.getHeader().append(element);
    } else {
        if (!nodeStack.empty()) {
            nodeStack.peek().getBody().append(element);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    XmlNodeInfo currentNode = nodeStack.empty() ? null : nodeStack.peek();
    if (currentNode != null) {
        currentNode.getBody().append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    String finalElement = xPaths.get(xPaths.size() - 1);
    String element = "</" + qName + ">";
    XmlNodeInfo currentNode = nodeStack.empty() ? null : nodeStack.peek();
    if (currentNode != null) {
        if (qName.equals(finalElement) && nodeStack.size() == xPaths.size()) {
            currentNode.getFooter().append(element);
            resultNodes.add(currentNode);
            nodeStack.pop();
        } else {
            if (currentNode.getName().equals(qName)) {
                currentNode.getFooter().append(element);
                nodeStack.pop();
            } else {
                currentNode.getBody().append(element);
            }
        }
    }
}

public List<String> getResults() {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (XmlNodeInfo node : resultNodes) {
        buildDocument(node, null, results);
    }

    return results;
}

private void buildDocument(XmlNodeInfo node, String childContent, List<String> results) {
    String body = node.getBody().toString();
    if (childContent != null) {
        body = body + childContent;
    }
    if (node.getParent() != null && !node.getParent().getName().equals(XmlNodeInfo.ROOT_NODE_NAME)) {
        String xmlContent = String.valueOf(node.getHeader()) + body + node.getFooter();
        buildDocument(node.getParent(), xmlContent, results);
    } else if (node.getParent() != null && node.getParent().getName().equals(XmlNodeInfo.ROOT_NODE_NAME)) {
        String finalContent = String.valueOf(node.getHeader()) + body + node.getFooter();
        results.add(finalContent);
    }
}

private String getAttributes(Attributes atts) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++) {
        String qName = atts.getQName(i);
        String value = atts.getValue(qName);
        builder.append(" ").append(qName).append("=").append("\"").append(value).append("\"");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

private boolean matchDefinedXpath(String nodeName) {
    String[] splitWords = nodeName.split(":");
    if (splitWords.length == 2) {
        String namespacePrefix = splitWords[0];
        String namespaceURI = namespaceContext.getNamespaceURI(namespacePrefix);
        Iterator prefixes = namespaceContext.getPrefixes(namespaceURI);
        while (prefixes.hasNext()) {
            String prefix = (String) prefixes.next();
            String elementName = prefix + ":" + splitWords[1];
            if (xPaths.contains(elementName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return xPaths.contains(nodeName);
    }
    return false;
}

private List<String> splitXpaths(String xPath) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(xPath)) {
        String[] splitWords = xPath.split("/");
        if (splitWords.length > 0) {
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String splitWord : splitWords) {
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(splitWord)){
                    results.add(splitWord);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

`

2) Create a bean to store node data:

`

public class XmlNodeInfo {

```
public static final String ROOT_NODE_NAME = "ROOT";

private String name;
private StringBuilder header;
private StringBuilder body;
private StringBuilder footer;
private List<XmlNodeInfo> children;
private XmlNodeInfo parent;

public XmlNodeInfo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    header = new StringBuilder();
    body = new StringBuilder();
    footer = new StringBuilder();
    children = new ArrayList<XmlNodeInfo>();
}

public StringBuilder getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public StringBuilder getBody() {
    return body;
}

public StringBuilder getFooter() {
    return footer;
}

public List<XmlNodeInfo> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void addChild(XmlNodeInfo xmlNodeInfo) {
    children.add(xmlNodeInfo);
    xmlNodeInfo.setParent(this);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public XmlNodeInfo getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(XmlNodeInfo parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

}

`

3) Run program:

`
public class MainApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    NamespaceContext namespaceContext = new XmlNamespaceResolver();
    String xPath = "/CATALOG/MAIN/CD";

    InputStream in = MainApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.xml");
    XmlNodeInfo rootNode = new XmlNodeInfo(XmlNodeInfo.ROOT_NODE_NAME);
    CustomSAXHandler customSAXHandler = new CustomSAXHandler(xPath, rootNode, namespaceContext);
    saxParser.parse(in, customSAXHandler);
    List<String> results = customSAXHandler.getResults(); // result strings
}
```

}

`

Maybe is not the best solution but it resolve my problems. Thanks all for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Just curious, does it retain the  <useful> node?

Comment: Sure. It retain all parents nodes except nodes which is presented in XPath.